# How could I delete a specific element that I have created in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, removechild

I'm making something for my own use that will allow me to quickly and easily stack commands (for Minecraft command block creations).

I have already created a button to create new textareas and a button to delete them. Presuming that there will be several textareas created, how could I delete a specific textbox in the middle of all of them (with the button to delete them)?

I have a div element to act as the parent, and actually was able to successfully delete the textareas AND buttons. My problem is after deleting even just one, I wasn't able to create more. And I noticed the text in the boxes would shift to the left.

The function :

```
function removeBox() {
            var div = document.getElementById("newText");
            var cats = document.getElementsByClassName("tAC");
            var catss = document.getElementsByClassName("tACB");
            div.removeChild(cats[0]);
            div.removeChild(catss[0]);
        }
```

Don't judge me because I named the variables cats!
The div :

```
<div id="newText">
    <textarea class="tAC" id="firstText"></textarea>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, the javascript isn't the code that worked, I changed it. Before it worked with arrays.

Comment: where is used removeBox(), and what is this in this function?

Comment: What is `this` in your code? You're going to need to show us some code that actually does something. There's far too little context here.

Comment: Ok, that was the code I began to write when I was trying illogical things.

Comment: I changed the element that the textareas and buttons used as a reference node, but the problem with the text shifting(and this is now what I need help with). I'm pretty sure that the first textarea is getting deleted.

Comment: This is the current code : function removeBox() {
    var div = document.getElementById("newText");
    var cats = document.getElementsByClassName("tAC");
    var catss = document.getElementsByClassName("tACB");
    div.removeChild(cats[0]);
    div.removeChild(catss[0]);
   }

Comment: Right now, I just need to know how I can select the button being pressed and its partner textarea as the nodes in
parentNode.removeChild(child);

Comment: The code you have provided does nothing. There  is not button, no click event hanlder, no script that creates the elements... Please provide that information.

Comment: When the buttons are created, I set their onclick attribute to that function. The code I have shown is only a fraction of the entire code.

Comment: Can you share more code so that we can see what you have actually tried?

Comment: The button is created in the div statement (sorry I didn't make that clear)

Comment: Ok, I used event.target as the child node and it worked fine!
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what you have posted, I am suggesting this.

Whenever a new `textarea` is created, create a new `button` within the div that holds the `textarea`. This way when the remove button is clicked, you can use `event.target` to get the button element which dispatched the event and from there you can use `event.target.previousSibling` to find the `textarea` and remove it from the DOM by calling `removeChild` on `event.target.parentNode`. I am not sure if this is what you expect, so I didn't share code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
cont.innerHTML += "<button id='b12' onclick='deleteMe("+'"b12"'+")'>b1b</button>"+
    "<button id='b22' onclick='deleteMe("+'"b22"'+")'>b2b</button>"+
    "<button id='b32' onclick='deleteMe("+'"b32"'+")'>b3b</button>";

window.deleteMe = function (elementId){
console.log("Borrando:", elementId );
document.getElementById(elementId).remove();
};
```

this is how it looks: [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/diego_carrascal/7oexqtju/)

The idea is to be able to identify the element, that is why setting an `id` for the elements you need to manipulate is very helpful. Hope it inspire you.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your setup and it seems to be working fine:

```js
    function removeBox() {
    var div = document.getElementById('new-text');
    var cats = document.getElementsByClassName("tAC");
    var catss = document.getElementsByClassName("tACB");

    var cats0 = cats[0];
    var catss0 = catss[0];
    
    div.removeChild(cats0);
    div.removeChild(catss0);
    }

var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]
button.addEventListener('click',removeBox,false);
```

```css
#new-text {
width: 200px;
}

#new-text p {
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
}

#new-text .tAC {
float: left;
}

#new-text .tACB {
float: right;
}

button {
clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="new-text">
<p class="tAC">cats0</p>
<p class="tACB">catss0</p>
<p class="tAC">cats1</p>
<p class="tACB">catss1</p>
<p class="tAC">cats2</p>
<p class="tACB">catss2</p>
</div>

<button type="button" />Click Me</button>
```